# Rails 5: How to create dynamic aggregations and filters in search results

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, search, aggregation, facet

I have a search form which searches and displays the search results for listing.

Listing schema is:

```
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "state"
    t.string   "zipcode"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.integer  "subcategory_id"
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "image"
    t.integer  "year"
    t.integer  "miles"
    t.string   "transmission"
    t.string   "color"
    t.string   "cylinder"
    t.string   "fuel"
    t.string   "drive"
    t.string   "address"
    t.boolean  "wholesale",         default: false
    t.integer  "price",             default: 0
    t.string   "newused"
    t.string   "vin"
    t.string   "stocknumber"
    t.string   "model"
    t.string   "trim"
    t.string   "enginedescription"
    t.string   "interiorcolor"
    t.string   "options"
    t.string   "imagefront"
    t.string   "imageback"
    t.string   "imageleft"
    t.string   "imageright"
    t.string   "frontinterior"
    t.string   "rearinterior"
    t.string   "bodytype"
    t.string   "make"
```

My search form gives users ability to search for newused, make, model, price, near and model.

```
<div id="Make" class="tabcontent1">
            <section class="formclass">

              <!-- f.select :transmission, ['Automanual','Automatic','Automatic 4 Speed','Automatic 5 Speed','Automatic 6 Speed','CVT','Manual'] -->
                <h3 style = "color:#F00000; text-align: center;"><strong><%= @carcount %> CARS LISTED!</strong></h3>

                <hr>

                <h3 style = "color:#7C064D;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> <strong>SEARCH CARS FOR SALE BY MAKE</strong></h3>
                <%= form_tag search_listings_path, method: :get, class: 'navbar-form navbar-center' do |f| %>

                <div class= "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12"> 
                    <%= select_tag :NewUsed, "<option>New</option><option>Used</option>".html_safe, style: "width: 100%; margin: 1% 0;" %>
                </div>

                <div class= "col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6"> 
                    <%= select_tag :category, include_blank: true, style: "width: 100%; margin: 1% 0;" %>
                </div>

                <div class= "col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6"> 
                    <%= select_tag :subcategory, include_blank: true, style: "width: 100%; margin: 1% 0;" %>
                </div>
                <!-- <div class= "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">  -->
                    <div class= "col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6"> 
                        <%= text_field_tag :minprice, nil, placeholder: 'Min Price', style: "width: 100%; margin: 1% 0;" %>
                    </div>
                    <div class= "col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6"> 
                        <%= text_field_tag :maxprice, nil, placeholder: 'Max Price', style: "width: 100%; margin: 1% 0;" %>
                    </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
                <div class= "col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6"> 
                    <%= text_field_tag :location, nil, placeholder: 'Near', style: "width: 100%; margin: 1% 0;" %>
                </div>
                <div class= "col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6"> 
                    <%= text_field_tag :radius, nil, placeholder: 'Radius', style: "width: 100%; margin: 1% 0;" %>
                </div>


                <div class= "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">              
                    <%= submit_tag 'Search', class: 'btn btn-danger', style: "width: 100%;" %>
                </div>
              <% end %>    
            </section>
      </div>
```

The search is a basic search method in the Listing model:

```
def self.search(params)
        if params
            listings = Listing.all
            listings = listings.joins(:category).where("categories.name like '#{params[:category].downcase}'") if params[:category].present?
            listings = listings.joins(:subcategory).where("subcategories.name like '#{params[:subcategory].downcase}'") if params[:subcategory].present?
            listings = listings.where("listings.NewUsed = '#{params[:NewUsed][0].upcase}'") if params[:NewUsed].present?
            listings = listings.where("price >= ?", "#{params[:minprice]}") if params[:minprice].present?           
            listings = listings.where("price <= ?", "#{params[:maxprice]}") if params[:maxprice].present?           


            if params[:radius].present?
                listings = listings.near(params[:location],params[:radius]) if params[:location].present?
            else
                listings = listings.near(params[:location],200) if params[:location].present?
            end

            listings

        else
            all
        end

    end
```

- I want to provide users sql/pgsql  aggregate filters. The aggregation
  produces filters depending upon the broader search results.
- Like if there are 20 cars shown, I want to generate a filter link on
  the left showing links to each transmission types and the number
  (like dynamic filters), when clicked, it should filter the search
  results further. It also gives a remove link
- Using scope in the model produces static filters, I want it to be auto generated depending upon what results are being shown.
  like aggregation in elastic search.
- Also, I want it to allow selection of multiple filters at same time.
- I wanna know specifically what to add in model, controller and the view to be able to do that. Just a simple example would work as well.

**Its used in all airlines, hotels, car selling sites. Please help me out or at least show me some direction.**